# how to read TextArea value and model in HttpPost in MVC2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm new in MVC2, so sorry for stupid question. I looked for nice answer, but can't find it. So my question is:

I have view:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<MyProject.MyDB.MyProducts>>" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="MyProject.MyDB" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="Content" runat="server">
    <% using (Html.BeginForm())
       {%>
    <table>        
        <%
            foreach (var item in Model)
            {%>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <%:item.name%>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%:String.Format("{0:g}", item.date)%>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <% } %>
    </table>
    <div>
        <%:Html.TextArea("MyTextArea")%>
    </div>    
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Send" />
    </p>
    <% } %>
</asp:Content>
```

My controller is:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ViewMyProducts(int id)
{
        List<MyProducts> myModel = GetMyProducts(id);
        return View(myModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ViewMyProducts(/*???What should I put here???*/)
    {
        if(/*I want "MyTextArea" value here*/ == something && myModel/*from view*/.count==5}
        {
            //do something
        }
        return View(myModel);
    }
```

So, in HttpPost I need myModel from view and value of "MyTextArea" from view. How can I get them?? I'll appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think that the following should work:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ViewMyProducts(string MyTextArea)
```

A helpful thing to do would be to explicitly call your Action in your Form - by changing this line:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm())
```

to

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("ViewMyProducts","ControllerName",HttpMethod.Post))
```

to ensure that the Submit action redirects it to the right Action.

As far as the model is concerned:

If you are just checking the Count - you could make a hidden field that returns the number of items in the "Model" like such:

```
<%: Html.Hidden("modelCount", Model.Count());
```

but if you want the entire Model - it would be need to be something like this:

```
<%: Html.Hidden("myModel", Model);
```

then you could further modify your Action to look something like this:

```
ViewMyProducts(string MyTextArea, int modelCount)
{
    //...
}
```

or

```
ViewMyProducts(string MyTextArea, IEnumerable<MyProject.MyDB.MyProducts> myModel)
{
    //...
}
```

Although you have access inside of the Controller to refresh the Model - so if you didn't need to pass back the entire thing you could still repopulate your view with a fresh call.

Comment: [HttpPost]
public ActionResult ViewMyProducts(string MyTextArea)
{............}
??????????
And myModel?

Comment: As much as I'm trying to stay out of Hidden Fields, I keep coming back to them :). I've tried your solution:

<%: Html.Hidden("myModel", Model);

ViewMyProducts(string MyTextArea, IEnumerable<MyProject.MyDB.MyProducts> myModel)
{
    //...
}

because I do need a whole model.
But it doesn't parse model from Hidden. In HttpPost, I get empty list. Any ideas?

Comment: I was a bit afraid of that happening - as I don't know if you will be able to pass back your entire model - just due to the way that MVC works. Your best bet might be to use another method of storage to keep your Model alive. Have you considered storing it in the Session / ViewData / TempData and then accessing it after the Post?

Comment: Yes, well done Rionmonster! Session did the job, and best of all, I'm not using Hidden. Great. Thank you all for quick answers.

Answer (score 2):

string myTextArea - or you could just check the FormCollection (I would recommend the named variable).

If you want to get the model back from the view, you will need to serialize it out as well in order to get back the values. If this is the case, I would convert the whole thing to a view model that either derives from your Model or has a public property that is your model, add a property for MyTextArea and then emit hidden input's for you model, named for the appropriate properties. Assuming that your model is persisted somewhere (database), I would just pass the key (id) and rehydrate the object from within the action result.

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ViewMyProducts(ViewMyProductsViewModel viewModel)
    {
        if(viewModel.MyTextArea == "something" && (IEnumerable<foo>)myModel).Count()==5))         {
          var model = repo.Get(myModel.First().Id);
          // do something with the model
        }
        return View(viewModel);
    }



<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<MyProject.MyDB.MyProducts>>" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="MyProject.MyDB" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="Content" runat="server">
    <% using (Html.BeginForm())
       {%>
    <table>        
        <%
            foreach (var item in Model)
            {%>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="hidden" name="viewModel.Id" value="<%:item.id%>" />
                <%:item.name%>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%:String.Format("{0:g}", item.date)%>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <% } %>
    </table>
    <div>
        <%:Html.TextArea("MyTextArea")%>
    </div>    
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Send" />
    </p>
    <% } %>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: I'm trying to avoid reaching to DB again in HttpPost. It seems logical to me that if I have myModel in HttpGet, I should have it in HttpPost with very little effort. Am I thinking in right direction?

Answer (score 0):

First of all You are rendering item.name and item.date as a text not html control. So You won't be able to receive it in controller method parameters.

Comment: You are wright, but I'm not trying to edit them, so my model should stay unmodified. I just want it back to HttpPost plus value of "MyTextArea".

Comment: I wouldn't do it like You try in the first place. But how about rendering model properties as readonly inputs? Then client won't be able to edit it.